# whats wrong with my code at the moment I cant update one row?

Tags: jquery, oop, datatables, codeigniter-3, php-7

how can I compare my id to my hash id if it's equal then update? the problem is at the moment when I want to update any row don't do it appropriate because doesn't detect my hidden input and update the same thing on any row? how can I fix it? this is what I got so far. I'm using datatables jquery and codeigniter
http://alasksoft.tk/login 
credentials admin - admin
when I want to access to this input `return  '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+data+'" >';` in my php controler i cant see because I havent in the doom because datatables jquery is hidding it how can I fix it without displaying it?

update controller

```
public function updateProduct(){
        $descripcion = $this->input->post('description');
        $cost_price =  $this->input->post('cost_price');
        $selling_price = $this->input->post('selling_price');
        $wprice = $this->input->post('wprice');
        $min_stock = $this->input->post('min_stock');
        $stock = $this->input->post('stock');
        $max_stock = $this->input->post('max_stock');
        $data = array(
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'precio_compra' => $cost_price,
            'precio_venta' => $selling_price,
            'precio_mayoreo' => $wprice,
            'existencia_minima' => $min_stock,
            'existencia' => $stock,
            'existencia_maxima' => $max_stock
        );
        if ($data['existencia'] > $data['existencia_minima']) {
            $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'));
        }elseif ($data['existencia_maxima'] < $data['existencia']) {
            $this->json(array('max_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al max'));
        }else{
           $this->products->updateProduct($data);
            $this->json(array('msg' => 'successfully added'));
           $this->json($data);
        }
    }
```

update model

```
public function isExistsProduct($data){
        $this->db->select('descripcion');
        $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
        $this->db->where('descripcion',$data['descripcion']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows() == 0 ? false : true;
    }

public function updateProduct($data) { 
        $this->db->update('storelte_articulos',$data); 
        $this->db->where('md5(id)',hash('md5', $this->input->post('id')));
    }
```

ajax table

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "lengthChange": false,
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [{
             extend: 'excelHtml5',
             exportOptions:{
                columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
             }
        },{
            extend: 'csvHtml5',
            exportOptions:{
                columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
            }
        },{
            extend: 'pdf',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
            }
        }],
        ajax: {
            url: URL_GET_DATATABLE,
            type: 'POST',
        },
        columnDefs:[{
            targets: -1,
            data: null,
            defaultContent: "<a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>"

        },{
            targets: 7,
            render: function (data) {
                return (data == 1) ? "<span class='label label-success'>active</span>":"<span class='label label-danger'>inactive</span>";
            }
        },
        {
            targets: 0,
            visible: false,
            render: function (data) {
               return  '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+data+'" >';
            }
        }],
        fnRowCallback: function (data,nRow) {
            if (nRow[7] == 0) {
                $(data).css({'background-color':'#f2dede'});
            }else if(nRow[7] == 1){
                $(data).css({'background-color':'#dff0d8'});
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please scale this down to only a minimal representation of the specific problem as per [mcve]. Then update the problem statement so it relates to the actual code. Hard to understand what your issue is

Comment: the problem is when I try to update any item as my controler  md5(id) = hash  then update , but when I do this updtae the whole database witht the same thing how can I fix it? code updated

Comment: The `where` statement  should be before `update` in `updateProduct`

Comment: it didnt work anyway

Answer (score 0):

Actually its kind of difficult to understand your problem but what I can figure from my experience is this line of code

```
public function updateProduct($data) { 
    $this->db->update('storelte_articulos',$data); 
    $this->db->where('md5(id)',hash('md5', $this->input->post('id')));
}
```

You are first updating the table than using where so change this to

```
public function updateProduct($data) { 
  $this->db->where('md5(id)',hash('md5', $this->input->post('id')));  
  $this->db->update('storelte_articulos',$data); 
}
```